# easyPhp phpMyAdmin access denied

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, easyphp

I installed EasyPhp (version 5.3.9) on my windows 7 laptop and try to use the included phpMyAdmin module (selected from the easyPhp admin home page), but I am unable to log in - I get the following error:

`#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

I did not change any file at all - so it should just use user=root and no password, I assume.

I checked other threads in SO but could not find any applicable solution.
I also tried uninstalling easyPhp completely and reinstalling it, but same problem, even when clearing all browser cache as suggested in one of the threads.

What to do next? How can I go use the MySQL module in EasyPhp when I can't even go to the admin tool?

Answer (score 5):

By default phpMyAdmin won't let you login without a password.

You will need to open `config.inc.php` in the phpMyAdmin directory, and make sure it is set as follows;

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Note that `'AllowNoPassword'` needs to be set to true.

Comment: the file \modules\phpmyadmin349x120816133321\config.inc.php contains exactly that already.

Comment: Are you sure that the MySQL server is running? This could also cause an access denied error.

Comment: OK so how can I check whether the mySQL submodule is running? Noteworthy is that when I try to access `http://127.0.0.1/home/mysql/`, I get an access denied error.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. Navigate to

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\dbserver\mysql5711x86x160717165359\bin
   ```

   and run

   ```
   mysql.exe
   ```
2. Type in:

   ```
   mysql_upgrade -u root -p
   ```

Apparently, this causes an upgrade which fixes some file problems.